# Parse Json using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse JSON in Oracle SQL.

Oracle DB version 12.1.0.2

```json
{
 "Rownum": "1",
 "Name": "John",
 "AddressArray":["Address1", "Address2"],
 "TextObj":[{
             "mName" : "Carol",
             "lName" : "Cena"
            },
            {
             "mName" : "Mark",
             "lName" : "Karlo"
            }
           ]
}
```

output should look like below:

[image]

Comment: You can do this using the ```JSON_TABLE``` function. What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried with JSON_TABLE but was not able to parse AddressArray.

Comment: @Shre - please edit your question to include the code from your attempt with `json_table` and the output or errors you got. We can then (hopefully) explain what you did wrong.

Comment: Please note there is a syntax error in the JSON. A comma is missing after ""Address2"]". So it has to be "... "Address2"], ..."

Comment: Edited my post added one more TextObj object.

Comment: Added new question as this was partially answered [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065792/parse-json-using-oracle-sql-json-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose "nested" will do the trick

```
select * from json_Table('{"Rownum": "1", "Name": "John", "AddressArray":["Address1", "Address2"], "TextObj":[{"mName" : "Carol","lName" : "Cena",}]}', '$' columns (rownr number path '$.Rownum',
                                            name varchar2(100) path '$.Name',
                                            mName varchar2(100) path '$.TextObj[*].mName',
                                            lName varchar2(100) path '$.TextObj[*].lName',
                                            nested path '$.AddressArray[*]' columns(AddressArray varchar2(100) path '$') 
                                           ));
```

My output:

| ROWNR | NAME | MNAME | LNAME | ADDRESSARRAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Carol | Cena | Address1 |
| 1 | John | Carol | Cena | Address2 |

Comment: Thanks @ekochergin.
This don't work if TextObj has one more object like below
`code` "TextObj":[{
             "mName" : "Carol",
             "lName" : "Cena"
            },
            {
             "mName" : "Mark",
             "lName" : "Karlo"
            }
           ]

Comment: @Shre, it makes TextObj an array as well. In this case you need to process it exactly as AdressArray

Comment: @Shre, sorry that make the question harder and I don't have the solution right now. Try this documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-BFA1FB9A-0F18-4ED2-B504-6855DC6705B5 or submit another question. Perhaps there is someone who could help to crack multiple JSON arrays

Comment: I tried this, But not getting expected result.
 `select * from json_Table('{
 "Rownum": "1",
 "Name": "John",
 "AddressArray":["Address1", "Address2"],
 "TextObj":[{
      "mName" : "Carol","lName" : "Cena"},
            {"mName" : "Mark","lName" : "Karlo"}
           ]
}', '$' columns ( 
rownr number path '$.Rownum',
name varchar2(100) path '$.Name',
nested path '$.TextObj[*]' columns
 (
   mName varchar2(100) path '$.mName',
   lName varchar2(100) path '$.lName'
  ),
 nested path '$.AddressArray[*]' columns(AddressArray varchar2(100) path '$') 
 ));`

Comment: @Shre, it'd be better to submit another question. I'm not sure I'll be able to find the solution until next week